# Screen flashes when changing fragments in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-webview

I have a viewpager with many fragments, each contains a webview. When viewpager scrolls to next fragment, the webview takes a delay to show on screen although it has been pre-loaded automatically by viewpager. This happens with Android 4.3 but not on Android 2.3.

I've set Viewpager.setOffScreenLimit() but it doesn't seem work. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: At last, this maybe related to HardwareAcceleration. When turn it off by adding **android:hardwareAccelerated="false"** in AndroidManifest, the screen  no longer flashes. But there's another problem: the viewpager now doesn't work smoothly as before.

Comment: you solve this problem ?

Comment: @SirukViktor Nope, I haven't found any solution but it's acceptable so I just move on.

Comment: @HoangHuu No, Please don't just move on, someone here has to fix it and doesn't have the choice of moving on :D Any ideas ?

Comment: @Benhammou: I'm currently has no free time to focus on this problem anymore. But I see many apps that have smooth viewpager scrolling. Maybe you can look for some alternative libraries :)
I found this, hope it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739804/mapfragment-causes-flickering-in-viewpager